# Calculate voltage gain of amplifier

Tags: amplifier

[image]

I know from testing and checking the answers that the correct answer is $$\frac{(25+5)}{5}=6$$
but I do not know why that is. The gain to the loopback or whatever to call it should be $$\frac{5}{30}≈0.17$$
And what is happening when we amplify that signal again, I cannot answer and that is my problem. Why is the gain 6?

Comment: google non inverting op amp

Comment: I honestly think that 15 seconds of googling would've led you to the wikipedia article on operational amplifier circuits, and that would've had an explanation of the rules involved

Comment: (also, with the quality of that illustration: wherever that picture is taken from probably contains exactly those rules, you just need to *read*)

Comment: Hint:  in negative feedback, the two op-amp inputs are driven to be equal.

Comment: All of the above **is** explained in the book where you got the picture from.

Comment: All that the book gave me was the formula g=A/(1+AB) where B=0.17 and A is unknown. How to solve the rest, I do not know

Comment: For a typical op-amp A is very big so \$ \dfrac{A}{1+AB} \approx \dfrac{1}{B} \$.  The other approach is to assume A is big enough to force both inputs to be the same. What \$ V_o \$ do you need for both inputs to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

In negative feedback, the two op-amp inputs are driven to be equal. This isn't magic. It's because if the inverting input goes higher, that will make the output node go lower (which then makes the inverting input go lower because they're connected through the resistor divider). And if the inverting input goes lower, it makes the output node go higher, which again drives the inverting input back where it needs to be.

So you have two equations:

$$V_- = \frac{5}{30}V_{o}$$

$$V_- = V_+ = V_i$$

Now do you see why the gain is 6 (\$V_o = 6 V_i\$)?